# AJAX form editing and design

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-interface, survey

I want to build into mt ASP.NET application the ability for users to fill up forms, but the forms are not something I can hard-code into my (Enterprise) software.

So I need one screen that lets end users create the forms. Doing it the 2.0 way, I just love what PollDaddy did in their survey editor (great job guys!). How do I replicate that? (don't worry pollDaddy, my app has nothing to do with survey and I am not at all in your domain (-: )

Since you need to login to the site to play with it, I made a 20 sec video of how it looks like. Please see below and tell me how to best replicate this (as simple as using JQuery tip? use an entire open source project? Buy something?)

Requirements are:

- support multiple types of elements (like multiple choice, free text, comboBox)
- drag and drop
- editing of order

*click image for video or [here](http://revver.com/video/1376799/affiliate/24133/pd-editor-example/)*

[http://frame.revver.com/frame/120x90/1376799.jpg](http://revver.com/video/1376799/affiliate/24133/pd-editor-example/)

Comment: yes.. but why ask, just give it your best shot, even if I wasn't, the idea of SO is that if you have something good to say, someone will find it usful at some point even if it is not the poster...

Answer (score 1):

The [AJAX control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) is free and would work for some of this items shown in the video. However, JQuery has tons of plugins it is easy to extend and even easier to use. I would suggest starting there and extending it where needed.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You could build it yourself using an AJAX framework like ASP.NET AJAX or even telerik controls.  You could use jQuery but ASP.NET AJAX is free and embeds well with ASP.NET pages. You could buy something, but I've yet to encounter packages as such.